# Edges with Direction in pyqtgraph GraphItem

Tags: python, pyqtgraph

I am trying to visualize a Control Flow Graph in Python using pyqtgraph. I have the following two problems.

1. How can I visualize the edges with a direction?
2. How can I visualize a self edge?

I tried looking into the documentation, but couldn't find. Obviously, I didn't get time to read it all!

Comment: Please be more specific--how do you want these to look? Arrows? Animation?

Comment: Only arrows. The self edge should be a curved edge starting and ending at the same node.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For direction, you might add a `pg.ArrowItem` at the end of each line (although this could have poor performance for large networks), and for self connections, `QtGui.QGraphicsEllipseItem` combined with an arrow.

Comment: Your answer worked! However I found another tool to do the whole thing much better. Will mention it in another answer here.

Answer (score 1):

While pyqtgraph is awesome, for my use case I found a much better tool to do this.

graphviz is a nice tool to develop Control Flow Graphs quite conveniently, and has a large number of features for this particular problem.